# Marimekko Chart: x axis ticks with irregular column width

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm just starting out with D3 and am quickly understanding that it's a pretty low level tool.
I'm using D3 to produce a Marimekko chart using this great example by Mike Bostock in
[b.locks](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005090), which is in all honestly a way too advanced place to start for me, but I started using D3 because I need a Marimekko chart, so here I am.

The x-axis here has ticks, 0 to 100% with 10% intervals. If my understanding of these code excerpts is correct...

*Set the x axis to a linear scale*

```
var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width - 3 * margin]);
```

*Give the x-axis 10 ticks*

```
var xtick = svg.selectAll(".x").data(x.ticks(10))
```

In my usage case , I'd like to have the x-axis ticks at the irregular intervals inherent to a Marimekko chart, and the axis labels to be the category, rather than a percentage.

The desired behaviour, as far as x-axis labelling, can be illustrated by this [b.locks example by 'cool Blue'](https://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/418d3f6d91915602e4fd)

I've got as far as understanding that I need a ordinal axis rather than a linear one (as in this excerpt of cool Blue's code)

```
var padding = 0.1, outerPadding = 0.3,
x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], padding, outerPadding);
```

How can I modify Mike Bostock's code to give me an example where the x-axis ticks label the column (ideally centrally), as opposed to providing a %age of the width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say that D3 is that low level, since it has a lot of abstractions. However, D3 is **not** a charting tool (and, in that sense, it is low level...), which makes things hard for a beginner.

However, you're lucky: the changes needed here are minimal. First, you'll pass the correct data to the selection that generates the axis...

```
var xtick = svg.selectAll(".x")
    .data(segments)
    //etc..
```

... and then use the same math for the translate, but adding half the sum:

```
.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + x((d.offset + d.sum / 2) / sum) + "," + y(1) + ")";
});
```

Of course, you'll print the key, not a percentage:

```
xtick.text(function(d) {
    return d.key
});
```

Here is the updated bl.ocks: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/09a8881e5bab2b12e7fd46c90a63b3fd/fd7b1a7b20f8436666f1544b6774778e748934ba